# For My Blogger <data:post.timestamp/> gives only HH:MM as result

Tags: javascript, blogger

When I use **data:post.timestamp** in my blogger site gives only HH:MM as result instead of the entire timestamp. How can I get the full date by using **data:post.timestamp**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I changed the Timestamp format under the settings>Language and formatting.